# What is the VBA code in Excel to Delete row(s) in column A:A if value is greater than 1 for all sheets in workbook

Tags: excel, vba, delete-row

What is the VBA code in Excel to Delete row(s) in column A:A  if value is greater than 1 for all sheets in workbook?

I have the code listed below already in one macro that runs, can someone help me write this set to be added to mine?

---

```
Sub BOMUpload_Formating()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        ws.Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.Delete
        ws.Rows("1:5").EntireRow.Delete
        ws.Columns("C:F").EntireColumn.Delete
        ws.Columns("E:M").EntireColumn.Delete

    Next ws

End Sub
```

---

Thanks, 
Brock

Comment: There is no value check in this code, you need to add it.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim LstRw As Long, sh As Worksheet, x
    Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
    For Each sh In Sheets
        With sh
            LstRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            For x = LstRow To 2 Step -1
                If .Cells(x, 1) > 1 Then
                    .Cells(x, 1).EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            Next x
        End With
    Next sh

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Sub RowKiller()
    Dim v As Variant, N As Long, i As Long, rKill As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Sheets
        N = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        If N > 1 Then
            Set rKill = Nothing
            For i = 1 To N
                v = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
                If IsNumeric(v) Then
                    If v > 1 Then
                        If rKill Is Nothing Then
                            Set rKill = ws.Cells(i, "A")
                        Else
                            Set rKill = Union(rKill, ws.Cells(i, "A"))
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next i
        End If
        If Not rKill Is Nothing Then rKill.EntireRow.Delete
    Next ws
End Sub
```